# Bigquery wildcard query returning expired rows

Tags: google-bigquery

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide. I am somewhat new to SQL and Bigquery and have not been able to find anything on my exact issue.

I am trying to use the bigquery wildcard functionality described below to query across two partitioned tables.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables

Each of these tables are partitioned based on a Date column, and some of the rows have now expired, due to the partition expiration time passing. When using a wildcard query, bigquery seems to be returning expired rows in addition to the expected rows.

Info on the test I am doing:
Table1 and Table2 both originally had 1000 rows (with varying dates) when uploaded to bigquery. They currently each have 77 rows because of expirations. The tables have identical schemas.

When I try to run the wildcard query below, bigquery is returning all 2000 original rows for some reason, even though the majority are expired based on the partition expiration setting and no longer shown in table1 or table2.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `dataset.table*`
```

However using a `UNION ALL` returns the expected 154 rows:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `dataset.table1`
UNION ALL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `dataset.table2`
```

It is my understanding these 2 queries should return the same data. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here and why bigquery is return 2000 rows in the wildcard query?

Comment: `mysql` <> `sql-server`. Please tag appropriately. This does look like MySQL as well, not SQL Server.

Comment: How do you know that you are only querying over `table1` and `table2`? The wildcard would match any other tables with that same prefix.

Comment: Expired partitions are deleted by a background process, like expired tables. They might not be deleted immediately at expiration time. We recently added an improvement to filter data from expired partitions, but looks like we only applied the fix on partitioned tables, not on wildcard table over partitioned tables. Please file a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't find this filed anywhere in the issue tracker, so I went ahead and opened a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80298797